# VHOST-USER interface between ovs-dpdk and a VM

Tags: networking, dpdk

I'm trying to understand the packet life-cycle in   ovs-dpdk  (running on host) communicating with  a VM through vhost-user interface:

1. packet is received via physical port to the device.
2. DMA  transfer   to mempools on huge-pages  allocated by dpdk-ovs - in  user-space.
3. ovs-dpdk copies this packet to the shared-vring of the associated  guest (shared between ovs-dpdk userspace process and guest)
4. no more copies in the guest - i.e. when any application running on the guest wants to consume the packet - there is a zero copy between the shared-vring and the guest application.

Is that correct?  How is part 4 implemented ?  This is a communication between OS in guest and application in guest, so how this is implemented with zero copy?

Answer (score 1):

> no more copies in the guest - i.e. when any application running on the guest wants to consume the packet - there is a zero copy between the shared-vring and the guest application.
>   Is that correct?

Not really. It is correct if you run a DPDK application in the guest. But if you run a normal kernel in the guest, there will be another copy between guest kernel and guest user space.

> How is part 4 implemented ?

See above. It is true only for DPDK applications.